# Voltage / amperage / setup for tingling sensation

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, biopotential, medical

There are small pens (powered by a single or double  1.5V battery) or other medical devices that upon touching your skin produce a tingling sensation.

**Main question**: I wonder to what voltage, amperage (or both) this sensation appear? Is the current suppose to be AC or DC? What frequency? In general **what are the conditions for the sensation to appear**?

(Optional) On the fun side can I achieve that with my Arduino board or a Raspberry?

Comment: the Arduino or the Raspberry Pi do not run on voltages that you could normally feel

Comment: @jsotola Let me contradict you. As my pen (search Google for "massager pen") which is used for medical purposes can be powered by a single AA 1.5V battery it is clear that an Arduino or Rasp which have bigger voltage can be used for similar purposes.

Comment: the pen produces a voltage that the arduno does not produce ... so, no, you cannot feel the arduino output ... if your question is actually `can I use the arduino as a power supply for a 1.5 V device?`, then yes, you can use it as a power supply if the current draw is within the arduino limit

Answer (score 1):

The threshold for sensing shock is in the ~2mA AC range, so the voltage would depend on how the electrodes are applied. Pulsing current is more likely to produce a sensation than DC.

More here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2763825/

Using about 10k ohms for skin resistance (somewhere between dry and damp), you would need about 20VAC to produce a perceivable shock.

The 'gag' pens you're referring to have transformers to boost up the shock for... greater shock value. Related: [electric chewing gum prank circuit diagram](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/72667/electric-chewing-gum-prank-circuit-diagram)

And a video about these things: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RA2dnzanch4

No doubt you could rig your R-pi to do this using a boost coil and pulse driver. The 'why' is up to you, but do keep in mind that making strong pulses could be hazardous. The 'toys' in the video are making pulses in the multiple hundreds of volts, although they're current limited. Could be dangerous to some sensitive people or situations.

By the way, shocking people as a horror prank... it's been done: https://www.sonypictures.com/movies/thetingler